# View remote chain in GUI

Tags: ganache, brownie, gui

I have a brownie project on a remote server. I'm interacting with it using VS Code and launch a ganache-cli mainchain fork using the `brownie console` command.

I have no problem issuing transactions using the command line, but when it comes to viewing them, as a newer dev it would be easiest for me to have something more similar than Etherscan or Ganache GUI to see each transaction

Is there any program or way I can configure Ganache to view this remote chain?

Answer (score 0):

use remix-ide `https://remix.ethereum.org/`.It is not a blockexplorer.But it will listen to all the events emitted by ganache-cli.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ganache-ui to check transaction log.Refer `https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache`